# CRTP Pattern yet store inhomogenous types in a datastructure

Tags: c++, design-patterns, crtp

I am interested in learning about CRTP.
I would like to implement a component system for an engine and I dont want to access components unity style

```
GetComponent("withThisName");
```

but rather at compile time (unreal style)

```
GetComponent<FromThisType>();
```

While its rather easy to implement CRTP I dont really get how to manage CRTP derived classes in a datasructure without introducing dynamic dispatching again.

The Wiki describes an example with shapes:

```
// Base class has a pure virtual function for cloning
class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {};
    virtual Shape *clone() const = 0;
};
// This CRTP class implements clone() for Derived
template <typename Derived>
class Shape_CRTP : public Shape {
public:
    virtual Shape *clone() const {
        return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this));
    }
};

// Nice macro which ensures correct CRTP usage
#define Derive_Shape_CRTP(Type) class Type: public Shape_CRTP<Type>

// Every derived class inherits from Shape_CRTP instead of Shape
Derive_Shape_CRTP(Square) {};
Derive_Shape_CRTP(Circle) {};
```

In this example I would still be able to do something like

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
```

BUT again there are virtual functions, and that is exactly what I tried to get rid of in the first place. I conclude, that I might still not get the CRTP right, or when it is used, on the other hand I see unreal engine using it, the way I want to use it.

Answer (score 4):

CRTP idiom isn't meant to give you a common interface for non homogeneous classes. It's almost all about static polymorphism, but the resulting types are completely different from each other.
Consider this:

```
template<typename T>
struct CRTP { /* ... */ };

struct A: CRTP<A> {};
struct B: CRTP<B> {};
```

`A` and `B` have nothing in common, they are different types and you cannot store them in a container unless you give them a common interface as a base class (that is what you suggested, even if you don't like it).
The fact that they are two specializations of the same class template doesn't provide you with a way to store them somewhere by simply ignoring the fact that they are different types.

Probably, CRTP isn't what you are looking for. Instead, consider using type erasure for your purposes.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Shape {
    template<typename Derived>
    static std::unique_ptr<Shape> clone_proto(void *ptr) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Derived{*static_cast<Derived *>(ptr)});
    }

public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    static std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Shape, T>::value, std::unique_ptr<Shape>>
    create(Args&&... args) {
        auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
        ptr->clone_fn = &Shape::clone_proto<T>;
        return ptr;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Shape> clone() {
        return clone_fn(this);
    }

private:
    using clone_type = std::unique_ptr<Shape>(*)(void *);
    clone_type clone_fn;
};

struct Rectangle: Shape {};
struct Circle: Shape {};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> vec;
    vec.push_back(Shape::create<Rectangle>());
    vec.push_back(Shape::create<Circle>());
    auto other = vec.at(0)->clone();
}
```

As you can see, in this case the type of the derived class is actually *erased* and what you get out of the `create` function is a `Shape`, nothing more. `Circle`s and `Rectangle`s are `Shape`s and you can easily create a vector of `Shape`s.
No virtual functions at all, but still a double dispatching to the internal data member `clone_fn` that gets back the right type and clones correctly the object.

Polymorphism is a (let me say) feature of the language that actually allows users to *erase* a bunch of types and correctly dispatch any function call at runtime. If you want to erase types at compile time you can do that, but it's not (and it cannot be completely) for free. Moreover it has nothing magic: if you want to erase a type, you need a mediator somewhere that is aware of what the type was and is able to get it back to work properly (virtual methods or static functions that act as dispatchers or whatever, if you want to *use* that type somehow you cannot avoid them).